# DNS resolution attacks by flooding spoofed replies

Tags: attacks, dns, sniffer, ip-spoofing

Each DNS request has an ID of 16bits. In the event that an adversary is unable to sniff the query, a way to spoof the DNS reply is to flood the resolver with many replies.

**Request from victim**

```
 Query ID: 1ac23
 What is the ip address of www.example.com
```

**Spoofed replies from adversary**

```
 Reply for ID 0001
 The ip address of www.example.com is 123.123.123.123

 Reply for ID 0002
 The ip address of www.example.com is 123.123.123.123

 Reply for ID 0003
 The ip address of www.example.com is 123.123.123.123

 ....

 Reply for ID 1ac23
 The ip address of www.example.com is 123.123.123.123

 ....
```

My question is, if the adversary can't sniff the ID (or the request itself) in the first place, **how does the adversary find out the domain that is requesting resolution, in this case `www.example.com`**?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a component of a broader targeted attack involving spear phishing.  You might send a link to the victim for Banking.Example.com and begin your DNS reply spam for that domain.  That way, you know which domain they are trying to resolve with DNS.

Answer (score 0):

In one scenario, an adversary has to access the communication channel between the client and the server. Thus the adversary can sniff that a query is coming from the client and also can see the transaction ID in the query.

In another scenario, the adversary does not have access to the queries (not an intermediate adversary). So, it needs to figure out a way to trigger the client to send a query. Triggering a query may involve social engineering or embedding hyperlinks in web pages (such as advertisements that trigger queries to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)).

Besides, if the target is a recursive resolver, the adversary can trigger it to send a query by sending a query to this recursive resolver (Having this assumption that the response is not already cached).